# (En|De)crypt data with static private/public key with RSA

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, private

I've seen many examples of how to use RSA in C# with random generated keys, but none with static keys. I need this is because my program client stores the public key (n, e) statically, and the server stores the private (d, n) and public keys statically too.

If I create a RSAParameters and store the `Modulus=n` and `Exponent=e` values and call `ImportParameters`, I can successfully encrypt data, but if I create a new RSAParameters and store the `Modulus=n` and `D=d` values, when I call the `ImportParameters` method, a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` is thrown.

Is there a way to decrypt the data with only the D and N values?

Comment: Could you post the code that exports/imports the components, and if possible the hexadecimal encoding of said parameters (obviously use a key for testing purposes only).

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the values in a PKCS#1/PKCS#8 format. That way you can retrieve the keys back from any framework as well. The best way to do this is to use the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) framework. I've included some pointers to questions about importing/exporting keys to/from a C# application.

[How to convert pkcs8 key file to DER format in #C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171658/how-to-convert-pkcs8-key-file-to-der-format-in-c)

[Creating PKCS1 public key in Net Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535563/creating-pkcs1-public-key-in-net-framework)